# SonarQube Msbuild Runner and Jenkins Unauthorized Error

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

I am getting the following error when trying to run Sonarqube MSBuild Runner with Jenkins. I am using SonarQube 4.5 and MSBuild SonarQube Runner 1.1. Any suggestions on how to resolve?

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.WebClientDownloader.Download(String url)
   at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.GetProperties(String projectKey)
   at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.FetchArgumentsAndRulesets(ProcessedArgs args, TeamBuildSettings settings, ILogger logger, IDictionary`2& serverSettings)
   at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.DoExecute(ProcessedArgs args, ILogger logger)
   at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.Execute(String[] args, ILogger logger)
   at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.Program.Main(String[] args)
Pre-processing succeeded.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the configuration file SonarQube.Analysis.xml. Confirm that the property sonar.host.url is correct and you have configured a valid sonar.login and sonar.password. The user you specified must be able to execute analysis. Open the SonarQube portal as admin and activate Administration - Security - Global Permissions. The user must be specified in Execute Analysis or must be a member of a group specified in Execute Analysis. Provide more details if this does not help

Comment: I've done as you suggested, but I still get the same error as the TC mentioned. Interesting enough, if i use the default admin user of SonarQube in SonarQube.Analysis.xml it works fine.

Comment: @phifi To keep in sync with the SonarQube deployment process i advise to upgrade to SonarQube 5.6.5 LTS. The recommended way to connect to the SonarQube portal is connecting using a [user token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token). Still check the [permissions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-GlobalPermissions) on global and project level once again.

Comment: this does not work for me but its weird that generating another token works. I'm not sure if previously generated token becomes stale that makes them cause the 401 error.