# SonarQube MSBuild Runner and TFS 2013 in VisualStudio Remote server returns unauthorized

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-4.5

I have edited a build definition from TFS 2013 inside of Visual Studio following the steps from [Setup of the MSBuild SonarQube Runner on the Build Agent Machine](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Setup+of+the+MSBuild+SonarQube+Runner+on+the+Build+Agent+Machine) and [Install the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Team+Foundation+Server+2013). I am getting the exact same errors as the question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514223/sonarqube-msbuild-runner-and-jenkins-unauthorized-error/) post as well as one that reads:

```
Exception Message: TF270015: 'MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '255'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

I've updated the SonarQube.Analysis.xml file with the correct information and followed the steps of the aforementioned post, updating the Global Permissions for Execute Analysis inside of SonarQube. I have tried updating IIS AppPool info for the service I am trying to build as well as updating Network Service access permissions, but to no avail. Anyone's advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If possible, can you share the configurations in "SonarQube.Analysis.xml" file? And did you check if the sonarqube server can be accessed from build agent machine?

Comment: Could you explain how I can check if the SQ server can be accessed from a build agent machine? Through researching the error, it seems like that could very well be the problem. Not sure I can share the configurations in the xml file because some of that information is private.

Comment: You can replace the private information with messy strings and then share the file. I'd like to follow the format in your file to see if I can reproduce the issue at my side.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<SonarQubeAnalysisProperties  default for SonarQube>
  
  <Property Name="sonar.host.url">http://blah:9000</Property>
  
  <Property Name="sonar.login">blah</Property>
  
  <Property Name="sonar.password">blah</Property>
  
  <Property Name="sonar.jdbc.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/blah;SelectMethod=Cursor</Property>
  
  <Property Name="sonar.jdbc.username">blah</Property>
  
  <Property Name="sonar.jdbc.password">blah</Property>

</SonarQubeAnalysisProperties>```

Comment: What is the version of SonarQube do you use?

Comment: Can you try removing "<Property Name="sonar.login">blah</Property> 
<Property Name="sonar.password">blah</Property>" section?

Comment: Sorry, it has been a while since I've been able to work on this, but removing that still caused the same errors.

Comment: did you ever made it work?

Comment: I somewhat did, but I went in a different direction with the project, creating an extension inside of a delivery manager. The problem pretty much came down to security permissions, and me not having them.